# Edit a manuscript after submit and approve it

Tags: paper-submission

I submitted my manuscript to a Springer journal and after viewing the submission, I approved it. But now I need to edit one of my references, but the Edit button is not available after approving the submission. How can I edit it? Should I submit a new manuscript?

Comment: Look for an "upload a revised copy" button. This is generally discouraged, but can be done within a few days after initial submission, without much of an issue. If several days have passed, then seek editor's approval.

Answer (score 3):

I think that submitting a new manuscript will just confuse them. The version you submitted will be checked and reviewed. You will get back a report and, hopefully, a request to update and resubmit changes. Make your changes then.

If that isn't enough to satisfy you, then contact the editor of the journal and ask for advice on how to proceed. But what you have discovered is pretty common.

The journal needs, for now, a stable version that can be sent to reviewers. You are just at the beginning of the process and will have time to fix things.

Comment: Submitting a new manuscript won't confuse them - modern editorial management systems have tools precisely to detect duplicate submission. It's an administrative hassle, though, and I agree that the easiest way is just to wait until revisions or copyediting (if the manuscript is immediately accepted) to make a non-essential change like this one.

Comment: Therefore, a mistake in referencing is common and does not cause the editor to reject it. right?

Comment: Thanks dear @Buffy, you helped me to control my stress.

Comment: Probably not worth a worry at this point. It might even be missed by reviewers. But journals for all practical purposes never publish the first version sent to them. You are lucky if you only need to revise once or twice.

Comment: Hmmm. Deer Buffy??? No, Dog Buffy. Ha.

Comment: Just be sure to inform the editor when at the time of proof editing you'll made whatever little change

Answer (score 1):

Just wait for the revision cycle to complete and incorporate the change at that time.  You are talking about a very small nitpicky change.  No reason to disrupt the cycle now.

Note, if they accept the paper without revision, write in at that time to request the change and with an edited version (or a brief email explaining that you will make the change in camera review, if they have that).